# jQuery .ajax call with dataType:html fails but Fiddler shows good response

Tags: jquery

I think this may be a cross-domain error. Firefox version 14.0.1, jQuery 1.5.1, is sending the request and getting a response, but throwing the error callback.

The ajax call looks like this:

```
$.ajax("http://theotherdomain.com/get.php", {
data: { parm : 1 },
dataType: "html",
success: handleit,
error: handleErr
});
```

The error function is called. No information other than "error"

However, the Fiddler trace shows this:

```
GET /get.php?parm=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: theotherdomain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:5195/Play.htm
Origin: http://localhost:5195
```

The response according to Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Encoding: gzip
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
...
```

So, it appears I am able to call this server via jQuery $.ajax - pass data to it, and it sends a response, but the data is not being passed back to me via the success callback.

1. Could this be a cross-domain problem?

If so, it doesn't seem to be very secure if the goal is to prevent the passing of data to another web server from a page other the host server. I'd be interested in comments on this point as well.

1. If not a cross-domain problem, then what am I getting wrong in the above scenario?